# Read text from neighbouring block using pytesseract

Tags: python, list, ocr, python-tesseract

[Click to view Scanned form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmK43.jpg)

I have done text extraction from image/scanned form now pytessarect reads this highlighted boxes in non sequential order. mean I got **Date Attended - from** text block then **Date Attended - to** text block and i want to read like **Date Attended - from** then **05-Mar-2013** like this.

I can't figure-out the highlighted text reading sequence of pytessarect.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: for more details about question check the attached image